# Расширение chrome, блокировка рекламы

Tags: javascript, html, css, chrome-extension

Всем привет, есть код который блокирует рекламу. Скрипт просто скрывает рекламу, но дает рекламе подгрузиться. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы реклама была не только невидимой, но и не подгружалась. И можно ли как-то высвятить кол-во заблокированных элементов, вроде статистики в popup.html файл?

```
window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let timerid = setInterval(function tick() {
    let
      div = document.querySelectorAll("div"),
      iframe = document.querySelectorAll("iframe"),
      embed = document.querySelectorAll("embed"),
      object = document.querySelectorAll("object"),
      img = document.querySelectorAll("img"),
      video = document.querySelectorAll("video"),
      param = document.querySelectorAll("param"),
      source = document.querySelectorAll("source"),
      yatag = document.querySelectorAll("yatag"),
      a = document.querySelectorAll("a");

    for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
      if (div[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || div[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        div[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < iframe.length; i++) {
      iframe[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++) {
      if (embed[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || embed[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1 || embed[i].src.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        embed[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
      if (object[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || object[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1 || object[i].data.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        object[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
      if (img[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || img[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1 || img[i].src.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        img[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
      if (video[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || video[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1 || video[i].poster.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        video[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
      if (param[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || param[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1 || param[i].name.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        param[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
      if (source[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || source[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1 || source[i].poster.indexOf("banner") + 1 || source[i].src.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        source[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < yatag.length; i++) {
      yatag[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i].className.indexOf("banner") + 1 || a[i].id.indexOf("banner") + 1 || a[i].href.indexOf("banner") + 1) {
        a[i].style.cssText = "display: none !important";
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
})
```

Каким образом мне нужно переписать код и какие методы нужно использовать?

Comment: Вам нужно не дописать, а полностью переписать :)

Comment: Нужно делать не "display: none", а совсем удалять элементы из кода страницы. Причём делать это до того, как графика и прочий контент начал подгружаться.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно узнать селектор блока с рекламой, найти все элементы на страницы через querySelectorAll. Вы получите массив элементов. Количество элементов будет равно количеству удаляемой рекламы. Потом циклом перебираете массив и удаляете элементы методом remove().

```
    window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    
    const ads = document.querySelectorAll("ADS selector")
    
    /* В консоль выводим количество блоков рекламы*/
    console.log(ads.length)
    
   ads.forEach(item => {
    
    /*Удаляем элементы*/  
     item.remove()
    
    })
}
```